# Botan static library linking error

Tags: c++11, botan

When I compile a source file using option:

***-lbotan-2***

which means using the shared library, nothing goes wrong.

But after I switch to option:

***-l:libbotan-2.a***

which means using the static library, an error occurs:

***//usr/local/lib/libbotan-2.a(pubkey_rsa.o): In function `std::future<std::result_of<Botan::Fixed_Exponent_Power_Mod const& (Botan::BigInt const&)>::type> std::async<Botan::Fixed_Exponent_Power_Mod const&, Botan::BigInt const&>(std::launch, Botan::Fixed_Exponent_Power_Mod const&, Botan::BigInt const&)':
rsa.cpp:(.text._ZSt5asyncIRKN5Botan24Fixed_Exponent_Power_ModEJRKNS0_6BigIntEEESt6futureINSt9result_ofIFT_DpT0_EE4typeEESt6launchOS9_DpOSA_[_ZSt5asyncIRKN5Botan24Fixed_Exponent_Power_ModEJRKNS0_6BigIntEEESt6futureINSt9result_ofIFT_DpT0_EE4typeEESt6launchOS9_DpOSA_]+0x379): undefined reference to`pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status***

I'm using Botan 2.1.0 and c++11 under Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using also `-pthread` or `-lpthread`?

Comment: @Jepessen No for both cases. But after I add the option, it works well. Does the shared library link pthread library automatically?